# How to get rid of double for loop in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I am currently making an autocomplete function that retrieves a bunch of information encoded by JSON and allows the user to search through it. There is a slight delay in the search results, and I think that a for loop inside of another for loop is the cause of this issue. Below is the Javascript file:

```
var username = [];
var businessname = [];
var fname = [];
var lname = [];
var fullname = [];
var clientid = [];
var bankArray = [];
var data_for_post = [];
var focusedArrayElement = "";
var started = false;
var currentSelectedList = 0;
var searchString = "";

$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case 40:
            if (!$("#results li:first").hasClass("selected") && !started) {
                $("#results li:first").addClass("selected");
                started = true;
            } else {
                if($("#results li.selected").next().length > 0) {
                    $("#results li.selected").next().addClass("selected");              
                    $("#results li.selected:first").removeClass("selected");
                }
            }
            assign = $(".selected").text();
            $(".autocomplete").val(assign);
        break;
        case 38:
            $("#results li.selected").prev().addClass("selected");              
            $("#results li.selected:last").removeClass("selected");
            if(!$("#results").siblings('.selected').length > 0) {
                started = false;
            }
            assign = $(".selected").text();
            $(".autocomplete").val(assign);
        break;
        case 13:
            assign = $(".selected").text();
            console.log(assign);
            $("#results").empty();
            $("#inner").text(assign);
        break;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "autocomplete.php?search=1",
        success: function(data) {                               
            $.each(data.client, function(key, value) {                          
                username.push(value.username);
                businessname.push(value.businessname);
                fname.push(value.fname);
                lname.push(value.lname);
                clientid.push(value.clientid);
                for(var i = 0; i < fname.length; i++) {
                    fullname[i] = fname[i] + " " + lname[i];
                }
            });
            bankArray = [username, businessname, fullname, clientid];           
            console.log(bankArray);
        }
    });
    $(".autocomplete").on("keyup change", function(e) {         
        console.log(e.keyCode);
        if(e.keyCode != 38 && e.keyCode != 40) {
            $("#results").empty();
        }
        currentSearchString = $(".autocomplete").val();
        if(currentSearchString) {   
            //$("#results").css('border-top', '1px solid black');
            for(var i = 0; i < bankArray.length; i++) {
                for(var j = 0; j < bankArray[i].length; j++) {
                    focusedArrayElement = bankArray[i][j].toLowerCase();
                    usernames = bankArray[0];
                    businessnames = bankArray[2];
                    fullnames = bankArray[3];
                    if(focusedArrayElement.indexOf(currentSearchString.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                        focused_businessname = bankArray[1][j];
                        focused_fullname = bankArray[2][j];
                        focused_clientid = bankArray[3][j];
                        postedData = focused_fullname + " -- " + focused_businessname;
                        if (!$(".clientid." + focused_clientid).length) { 
                            $("#results").append("<li id='" + (j + 1) + "' class='clientid " + focused_clientid + "'>" + postedData +  "</li>");    
                        }           
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        else {
                $("#results").empty();
            started = false;
        }       
    }); 
});
```

The basic principle is that when the document readies, an ajax call pushes all of the JSON data into a multidimensional array with different categories of information. From here, a first for loop searches through each array in the bankArray, and the second searches through each element of the current array. If the current search string in the input field matches the focused element from the array, it appends that information to a div below.
I feel as if the code is inefficient in how it deals with the JSON data and checks through it. If anyone has any suggestions on how to optimize the code, that would be great.

Comment: How much of a delay, and how much data are you sorting through?

Comment: the delay only seems to be around 200-300 ms, but the objective is to have an instant search. That is why the AJAX only grabs the JSON data once, not at every search.

Comment: If you're using Chrome I'd recommend adding some console.time() and console.timeend() calls to debug where you may be having performance issues. Its hard to test it out myself without a sample set of data similar in size  and format. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api